# Preprocessor target checking

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, macros, c-preprocessor, target

I want to use preprocessor commands to test which target I'm compiling for.
Every example I read told to do that :

- Add a preprocessor macro in my target.
- Do this :

  ```
  #ifdef TARGET_NAME_MACRO
      NSLog(@"TARGET_NAME");
  #else
      NSLog(@"ANOTHER_TARGET");
  #endif
  ```

However, it isn't working. This condition passes whenever I do it in my TARGET_NAME's file but never passes when doing so in another target's file.
I need to test in another target's file if I'm running it in Test mode.

I've tried a few things, none worked out.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you have the define set up in the build commands?

Comment: Project > Mytarget > Preprocessor macros > TEST

Comment: Is it `TEST` or `TARGET_NAME_MACRO` because if the `#ifdef` does not match what you set in the build commands, it won't work

Comment: Of course it's matching, i told you it's working in Mytarget files, but it's not in others target files ='(
Maybe it's not the way to do so.

Comment: The build settings are for a specific target, so if you need it to work for multiple targets, you need to set the preprocessor macro in each target's build commands

Comment: i tried by setting my macro to 1 in my target, and 0 in the others. Using a #if instead of a #ifdef. But still didn't work.

Comment: You want it to trigger in other targets, or not?

Comment: I want it to trigger only if i'm running my project in MyTarget.
The test is not located in MyTarget's files.
It's about unit-testing. I want my app HTTPRequest to be synchronous if i'm running in unitTesting.

Comment: And what isn't working, it is still passing the #if in other targets, or failing the #if in the intended target

Comment: It looks like preprocessor macros are local to the target. I set it to 1 in my Unit testing macros, 0 in my normal target. It fails if i test in the normal target's files, and pass if i test in unit testing's files.
I want it to trigger in normal target's files if i'm launching the app in testing mode on Unit-Testing target.